# How to change lightning-combobox icon

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

How to change lightning-combobox icon from arrow to for instance clock? I can not understand how to do that. and its possible to do?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/moAdF.png

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no specific attribute in `lightning-combobox` to do that. In my opinion, the chevron is more visually consistent but I understand that requirements can differ.

The best way to do achieve this is to build your own component. You can fork [this](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/combobox/combobox.html) and make a change [here](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/blob/ca141af915849320fa38bbf667b7de53f6bb30fc/force-app/main/default/lwc/baseCombobox/baseCombobox.html#L18)

Comment: thank you for your quick response. i will look